# A currency called a mathik has only 1, 3, and 6 mathik bills. How many ways can one pay 300 mathiks?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, integer-partitions

I have an idea on how to solve it, but there are too many ways for substitution. Do I use recursion?
For avoidance of doubt, paying 297 1-mathik bills and then a 3-mathik one is the same as paying a 3-mathik bill and then 297 1-mathik bills.

Comment: Is their no limit of number on denominations?

Comment: What do you mean? I think the instructions are clear. There are only 1,3, and 6 "dollar" bills, if that's what you mean.

Comment: You could count them with order included and then try to follow the tree diagram to remove the double counting of equivalent orderings. Counting with ordering included you have $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-3)+f(n-6)$, until you get to $n=5$. That's a linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients, so in theory it is straightforward to solve, though the roots of $x^6-x^5-x^3-1$ might not necessarily be easy to find...

Comment: Generating function $(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\dots)(1+x^6+x^{12}+x^{18}+\dots)=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^3)(1-x^6)}$.  Find the coefficient of $x^{300}$ of that.

Comment: I'm very confused by both answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that there are only the three denominations $1,$ $3,$ and $6,$
where $1$ divides $3$ and $3$ divides $6,$ helps keep things less complicated than they might have been.

To avoid counting the same way of paying the bill twice, you could pay the six-mathik bills first, then the three-mathik bills, then the one-mathik bills.

You *could* solve the problem by recursion. I'd recommend only dealing with total debts that are divisible by $6,$ and keeping track not only of how many ways you can pay each with just six-, three-, and one-mathik bills but also how many ways you can pay using just three-mathik and one-mathik bills.

The number of ways you can pay $6(n+1)$ mathiks then is the number of ways
you can pay the first $6$ mathiks with a six-mathik bill and the remaining $6n$ mathiks using any combination of bills,
plus the number of ways you can pay the first $6$ mathiks with $2$ three-mathik bills and the remaining $6n$ mathiks using any combination of three-mathik and one-mathik bills, plus one way in which you pay the entire debt with $6(n+1)$ one-mathik bills.

---

Here's another approach:

The greatest number of six-mathik bills one can use when paying $300$ matiks is $50$ bills.
There is only one way to pay the bill while using $50$ six-mathik bills.
$$50\times6=300.$$

You can also pay using exactly $49$ six-mathik bills and some other bills.
There are exactly three ways to do this:
\begin{align}
49 \times 6 + 2\times3 = 300,\\
49 \times 6 + 1\times3 + 3\times1= 300,\\
49 \times 6 + 6\times1 = 300.\\
\end{align}

There are exactly five ways to pay while using exactly $48$ six-mathik bills:
\begin{align}
48\times 6 + 4\times3 = 300,\\
48\times 6 + 3\times3 + 3\times1= 300,\\
48\times 6 + 2\times3 + 6\times1= 300,\\
48\times 6 + 1\times3 + 9\times1= 300,\\
48\times 6 + 12\times1 = 300.\\
\end{align}

Do you see a pattern? Can you find the answer now?

Comment: So all the amounts are odd, starting at 3?

Comment: @GerardL. Starting at $1$, in fact (the first case just didn't have nice indented equations because it is very simple).

Comment: @Ian Thanks for the idea--now I've made the equation in the first case "nicely indented" too, so it might be more obvious that it is the first way to pay the debt.

Comment: @DavidK There's one small error in the fourth to the last line, the second '4' should be '2.' $48\times 6 + 4\times3 + 6\times1= 300$ should be $48\times 6 + 2\times3 + 6\times1= 300$

Comment: @Arby Thanks, too much cutting and pasting and overwriting. I must have missed that one.

Comment: No worries, I'm still trying to wrap my mind around your first method. Then I'll be off to investigate generating functions mentioned above. I find this type of problem to be very accessible, and I feel like problems such as this could be good gateways into math for those new to or afraid of the subject.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> In dealing with *constraints*, *Iverson Brackets* are quite useful . Namely,

\begin{align}
&\bbox[#ffe,10px]{\ds{\sum_{a_{1} = 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{a_{3} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_{6} = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{a_{1} + 3a_{3} + 6a_{6} = 300}}} =
\sum_{a_{6} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_{3} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_{1} = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{a_{1} = 300 - 3a_{3} + 6a_{6}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{a_{6} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_{3} = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{300 - 3a_{3} + 6a_{6} \geq 0} =
\sum_{a_{6} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_{3} = 0}^{\infty}
\bracks{a_{3} \leq 100 - 2a_{6}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{a_{6} = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{100 - 2a_{6} \geq 0}
\sum_{a_{3} = 0}^{100 - 2a_{6}}1 =
\sum_{a_{6} = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{a_{6} \leq 50}\pars{101 - 2a_{6}} =
101\sum_{a_{6} = 0}^{50}1 - 2\sum_{a_{6} = 0}^{50}a_{6}
\\[5mm] = &\
101 \times 51 - 2\,{50 \times 51 \over 2} = \bbx{2601}
\end{align}

Comment: This is identical to Markus's but this presentation is original and extendable to other problems, I didn't know about Iverson brackets.

Comment: @zwim Thanks. What makes Iverson Bracket wonderful is that it guides the calculation to the final result.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following possible partitions

$300=\underbrace{\underbrace{1+1+1}_3+\underbrace{1+1+1}_3}_6+\underbrace{\underbrace{1+1+1}_3+\underbrace{1+1+1}_3}_6+\underbrace{1+1+1}_3+1+1+...+1=$

You can regroup any packet of three bills of $1\,\mathtt{mathik}$ into bills of $3\,\mathtt{mathiks}$ and you can make at most $100$ such packets.

But then you can also regroup two bills of $3\,\mathtt{mathiks}$ into bills of $6\,\mathtt{mathiks}$. From a partition that contains $n=(2k)$ or $n=(2k+1)$ bills of $3\,\mathtt{mathiks}$ you can make at most $p=k+1$ partitions.

So I will describe the partitions with the number of packets of $3$ we can make

$\begin{array}{r|l|l|l}
n & \text{3 bills partitions} & p & \text{6 bills partitions*}\\
\hline
0 & 111111111111111111111111111111111111....1 & 1 & \text{-}\\
1 & 3111111111111111111111111111111111....1 & 1 & \text{3}\\
2 & 33111111111111111111111111111111....1 & 2 & \text{33, 6}\\
3 & 333111111111111111111111111111....1 & 2 &\text{333, 63}\\
4 & 3333111111111111111111111111....1 & 3 &\text{3333, 633, 66}\\
5 & 33333111111111111111111111....1 & 3 &\text{33333, 6333, 663}\\
...& ................................ & ...\\
98 & 33333333....3111111 & 50\\
99 & 33333333....33111 & 50\\
100 & 33333333....333 & 51\\
\end{array}$

(*) I do not write the trailing $111...$ if any.

So we get $N=1+1+2+2+3+3+...+50+50+51=2(1+2+3+...+50)+51$

> $N=2(\frac{50\times 51}{2})+51=51^2=2601$

Answer (score 0):

The following holds:

- The number $ \color{blue}{j}$ of $6$ mathik bills we can use is $0\leq j \leq \frac{300}{6}=50$.
- Since then $300-6j$ mathiks are left, the number $\color{blue}{k}$ of $3$ mathik bills we can use is $$0\leq k\leq\frac{300-6j}{3}=100-2j$$
- The rest is left for $1$ mathik bills.

> We conclude the number of possibilities is
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{\color{blue}{j}=0}^{50}\sum_{\color{blue}{k}=0}^{100-2j}1&=\sum_{j=0}^{50}(101-2j)\\
> &=51\cdot 101-2\cdot\frac{50\cdot 51}{2}\\
> &=51^2\\
> &=\color{blue}{2601}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The coefficient on $x^{300}$ in the following polynomial:
$$
\left(\sum_{k=0}^{300}x^k\right)
\left(\sum_{k=0}^{100}x^{3k}\right)
\left(\sum_{k=0}^{50}x^{6k}\right)
$$
which is $2601$ according to Maple.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the problem in general, that is, replace $300$ with $n$, you can let the number of ways be $a(n)$. By looking at the first few values of $a(n)$ you will see that each value repeats three times. That is, let $b(n)=a(3n)$, then $a(n)=b(\lfloor n/3\rfloor)$. By searching in OEIS, http://oeis.org/A002620 you will find that the sequence $b(n)$ is the sequence of quarter-squares with a different offset. See more details in the OEIS link. In your case the answer is $\lfloor(300/3+2)^2/4\rfloor=2601$.